# Collection.sort does not work for my Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, collections

I created my own MyArrayList but it can not be sorted. A normal Arraylist can be sorted by `Collections.sort` but mine can not. Could some one tell me where is wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestMyArrayList
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] subjects = {"EIE320", "EIE558", "EIE375", "EIE424"};
        Integer[] marks = {90,85,70,80};
        MyArrayList<String> sList = new MyArrayList<String>(subjects);
        Collections.sort(sList);
        sList.print();
        MyArrayList<Integer> mList = new MyArrayList<Integer>(marks);
        Collections.sort(mList);
        mList.print();
    }
}

public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E>
    implements List<E>
{    
    private List<E> data;

    public MyArrayList()
    {
    }

    public MyArrayList(E[] inputdata){
        super();
        data = new ArrayList<E>();
        for(E e:inputdata){
            data.add(e);
        }
    }

    public void print(){
        for(Iterator iter = data.iterator();iter.hasNext();){
            System.out.print(iter.next() + " ");
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create a List inside a List you have two lists. Some methods use one List and some use the other.  You would need use the debugger to see this.  I suggest you either use delegations (i.e. don't extend ArrayList) or you use inheritance, but don't do a bit of both.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor of `MyArrayList` is wrong. Since you are extending `ArrayList`, you shouldn't create another `ArrayList` instance in the `MyArrayList` constructor. Just add the elements to `this` `ArrayList`.

When you call `Collections.sort()` on your `MyArrayList` instance, it doesn't sort the `data` member `List`.

```
public MyArrayList(E[] inputdata){
    super();
    for(E e:inputdata){
        super.add(e);
    }
}
```

Your `data` member is not needed. You would only need such a member if you use composition instead of inheritance, in which case your class wouldn't extend `ArrayList`.

You should also modify your `print` method :

```
public void print(){
    for(Iterator iter = iterator();iter.hasNext();){
        System.out.print(iter.next() + " ");

    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the source code of `Collections.java` you will see that `Collections.sort` calls the `sort` method defined in the concrete list which in this case is 'MyArrayList.java'. You have not provided this method so your class inherits this from the super class `ArrayList.java` Now if you see the source code of `ArrayList.java` you will find that `sort` method defined in it does the process of sorting on the `Object[] elementData;`. You have not set your data in `elementData` (defined in `ArrayList.java`).

You can use `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` constructor from your `public MyArrayList(E[] inputdata)`. You will have to transform the `inputdata` and then instead of calling `super()`, you should call the constructor `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`.

As a suggestion, also pointed by answer given by Eran, you can use composition, in you class you can have a reference to ArrayList and then can use it for addition, deletion and do sorting on it (define a method sort and within it call Collections.sort on the object of ArrayList you have).

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up that you can use `Arrays.asList()` instead of doing what you are doing here.

```
    String[] subjects = {"EIE320", "EIE558", "EIE375", "EIE424"};
    ArrayList<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(subjects));
```

If you are doing this as an excercise that's fine, but I would usually avoid re-writing `Collections` classes if at all possible.